# How to fix : "TypeError: 'StandardScaler' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm getting the error "TypeError: 'StandardScaler' object is not iterable".

The error happens in this part of my code:

```
    gps = joblib.load('gps.zip')
    accuracies, remain_features, models = joblib.load(os.path.join(bagging_dir, model_fname))
    remain_features = [c for c in remain_features if c != 'index']

    y_preds = []
    scalers = joblib.load('scalers.zip')
    gp, scaler, model = list(zip(gps,scalers, models))[0]
```

Specifically, this line:

```
gp, scaler, model = list(zip(gps,scalers, models))[0]
```

How do I fix this error? If you know, please tell me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that comes from this line:

```py
remain_features = [c for c in remain_features if c != 'index']
```

I think you can't use a list comprehension on that, maybe try converting it into a list first?

Comment: Hi! Sorry. It's actually from this part :

gp, scaler, model = list(zip(gps,scalers, models))[0]

Any idea how to fix this?